# $("#select option:second").val() jquery - keep select second value of select box option

Tags: jquery

I am able to keep  select the first and last value of a select box

```
$("#selbox").val($("#sel_selbox option:last").val());

$("#selbox").val($("#selbox option:last").val());
```

How can i keep select the second value ?

```
$("#selbox").val($("#selbox option:second").val());
```

THis is giving error. Is there any option to keep select by giving index ?

Comment: `$('#selbox option:eq(1)')` http://jqapi.com/#p=eq-selector

Comment: @sod yu should have post this answer man . Thanks Sod  from Zod .. :-)

Comment: This is why i ask Meta , good comments also should conted somewhere http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97052/is-our-great-comments-counted-somewhere-in-so-in-our-profile and people did not gave any great response!! :-(

Comment: I was not in the mood for an answer. Just a few chars of code and a link feels so short :D

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you want the special jQuery `eq()` selector.

```
    $("#selbox").val($("#selbox option:eq(1)").val());
```

Answer (score 12):

The selector way of doing this is [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector), [as already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713143/select-optionsecond-val-jquery-keep-select-second-value-of-select-box/6713184#6713184).

However, this is not the best method.  Because `eq` is a non-standard, jQuery-specific extension, the whole query has to be parsed by jQuery's selector engine.  None of the selection is handled by the browser's native selection capabilities.  This means that the selection will be *much* slower.

If you make a simple selection and then cut it down with jQuery methods, you will get much better performance, because the browser's native selection function (called `querySelectorAll`) will handle everything that it can, which will provide a big speed boost.

```
$('#selbox option').eq(1).val();
$('#selbox option').last().val();
$('#selbox option').first().val();     // same as .eq(0).val();
```

See:

- [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)
- [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last)
- [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first)

Answer (score 2):

or like this:

```
$('#selbox').find('option').eq(1).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing it.

```
$("#selbox").val($("#selbox option").eq(1).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to hide all but the first 2 options and used this.

```
$("#DDLId").find('option:not(:first)').not(":first").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).parent('span').length == 0 ? this : null;
}).wrap('<span>').hide();
```

NB this uses the "hide with a span" trick rather than simply using hide() as IE won't hide options directly.

use `.unwrap().show()` to reshow the hidden options.